# ServiceBusClient for Azure Service Bus - reuse tcp connections like with HttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, .net-5, httpclientfactory

I have many CRUD APIs that are communication with each other over HTTP calls (.NET 5)
To avoid too many open tcp connections, I use [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) via DI in all those services. This works well and I do not experience too many connections that are opened via HTTP.

But my Azure App Services are still complaining about too many SNAT-connections:

[image]

I guess that the reason is the Azure Service Bus.
Each call of my APIs will write events to the bus.
To do this I create a new instance on each call:

```
            await using (ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(_serviceBusConnectionString))
                {
                    var messageObject = new { message.Name, message.Body };
                    var messageJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageObject);
                    ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(_topicName);
                    await sender.SendMessageAsync(new ServiceBusMessage(messageJson));
                }
```

Many developers are using HttpClient like this (what is a bad idea, read why in the article above).
The solution for HttpClient is the AddHttpClient method, provided by .NET for this purpose.

But what about Azure Service Bus? There is nothing like an AzureServiceBusFactory or so and adding the AzureServiceBus as a Singleton would not be a good idea, because the configuration should be different on each call.

How can I make sure that the connection pool is also reused for Azure Service Bus connections? Is there any best practice I missed? Or do you think the problem with the connections has another cause?

Edit:

The accepted answer is right. This works fine and my errors disappeared.
Just use the following to add the service bus client:

```
            services.AddAzureClients(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddServiceBusClient("your-connection-string");
            });
```

After this, you can easily get the client via DI in all your services.

Comment: ServiceBusClient is the factory and you should cache it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But what about Azure Service Bus? There is nothing like an
> AzureServiceBusFactory or so and adding the AzureServiceBus as a
> Singleton would not be a good idea, because the configuration should
> be different on each call.

It is actually the other way round. Service Bus team recommends that connection to your Service Bus should be registered as Singleton only using [`ServiceBusClientBuilderExtensions`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Compatibility/ServiceBusClientBuilderExtensions.cs) and should not be closed or disposed after every operation.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2#reusing-factories-and-clients):

> The Service Bus objects that interact with the service, such as
> ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusSender, ServiceBusReceiver, and
> ServiceBusProcessor, should be registered for dependency injection as
> singletons (or instantiated once and shared). ServiceBusClient can be
> registered for dependency injection with the
> ServiceBusClientBuilderExtensions.
>
> We recommend that you don't close or dispose these objects after
> sending or receiving each message. Closing or disposing the
> entity-specific objects (ServiceBusSender/Receiver/Processor) results
> in tearing down the link to the Service Bus service. Disposing the
> ServiceBusClient results in tearing down the connection to the Service
> Bus service.

Please see this link for complete recommendations from Service Bus team: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2.

Comment: While service bus client becomes singleton, service bus senders and receivers are not, with `ServiceBusClientBuilderExtensions`. Is there a way to inject `ServiceBusSender` as a dependency? I couldn't find any article for it like the one you've mentioned in the answer.

Comment: This answer replicates the official documentation but I believe the official documentation to be incomplete and that AMQP link objects _should_ be disposed; _however_, it is better to reuse them than to constantly recreate them. See also https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.AzureServiceBus/issues/75, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70473724/482758.