# Migration from Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm trying to update this function to make use of `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` and drop `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` altogether, however, I can't seem to find any resources for this. Anybody knows how to send a message to a topic using this package?

The older function is:

```
public async Task SendMessageToServiceBusTopic<T>(T request, string topicSubName, string submissionNumber)
{
    ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder serviceBusConnectionStringBuilder =
        new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(settings.ServiceBusConnectionString)
        {
            EntityPath = settings.ServiceBusTopic
        };
 
        TopicClient topicClient = new TopicClient(serviceBusConnectionStringBuilder);

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
        await topicClient.SendAsync(new Message(bytes)
        {
            CorrelationId = context.CorrelationId,
            Label=topicSubName,
            UserProperties = { new KeyValuePair<string, object>("TrackingId", submissionNumber) }
        });          
}
```

So far I have managed:

Am i headed in the right direction?

```
public async Task SendMessageToServiceBusTopic<T>(T request, string topicSubName, string submissionNumber)
{
    ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(settings.ServiceBusConnectionString);
    ServiceBusSender s = client.CreateSender(settings.ServiceBusTopic);

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
    await s.SendMessageAsync(new ServiceBusMessage(bytes));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can construct a Service Bus Client each time, it's not ideal. Assuming you're using the latest In-Proc SDK, you can use one of these options:

```
[FunctionName("PublishToTopic")]
public static async Task Run(
    [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
    [ServiceBus("<topic_name>", Connection = "<connection_name>")] IAsyncCollector<ServiceBusMessage> collector)
{
    await collector.AddAsync(new ServiceBusMessage(new BinaryData($"Message 1 added at: {DateTime.Now}")));
    await collector.AddAsync(new ServiceBusMessage(new BinaryData($"Message 2 added at: {DateTime.Now}")));
}
```

Alternatively,

```
[FunctionName("PublishWithSender"]
public static async Task Run(
    [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
    [ServiceBus("<topic_name>", Connection = "<connection_name>")] ServiceBusSender sender)
{
    await sender.SendMessagesAsync(new[]
    {
        new ServiceBusMessage(new BinaryData($"Message 1 added at: {DateTime.Now}")),
        new ServiceBusMessage(new BinaryData($"Message 2 added at: {DateTime.Now}"))
    });
}
```

For Isolated Worker SDK it's somewhat different. See [this post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/functions-isolated-worker-sending-multiple-messages) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation like you (trying to migrate to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus which is now the recommended NuGet from Microsoft).

You can have a look at the migration guide from their Github to have an idea of how to make the transition smoother:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/MigrationGuide.md

/!\ **IQueueClient** and **ITopicClient** (both coming from Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus) have been merged into a single object called **ServiceBusSender**.

Why ? to make our life easier ! Indeed, under the hood, **ServiceBusSender** now takes care of the process of sending the message, especially since a queue and a topic cannot have the same name if I'm not wrong.

Here's a sample code of mine to send a message using the new library:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Send a message by serializing as JSON the object in input. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="queueOrTopicName">Name of the queue or topic where the message will be sent.</param>
    /// <param name="messageToSend">Any C# object</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task SendMessage(string queueOrTopicName, object messageToSend)
    {
        //ServiceBusSender should not be disposed (according to the documentation, Github, etc.)
        await using ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString: "Your-ServiceBus-ConnectionString");
        await using ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(_queueOrTopicName);

        // create a message that we can send. UTF-8 encoding is used when providing a string.
        ServiceBusMessage message = BuildServiceBusMessage(messageToSend);

        // Finally send the message
        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
    }

    private ServiceBusMessage BuildServiceBusMessage<T>(T entity)
    {
        string serializedMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity); // Still using Newtonsoft.Json but I don't see any obstacles of using System.Text.Json.
        ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(serializedMessage)
        {
            MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        };

        return message;
    }
```

If you have any needs to do Dependency Injection (to re-use the same ServiceBusClient object and avoiding instanciating ServiceBusClient for each message you want to send for example), you can refer to this stackoverflow that I discovered this week

[How to register ServiceBusClient for dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688838/how-to-register-servicebusclient-for-dependency-injection)

Comment: `ServiceBusClient` and its instantiated "AMQP link" objects, like `ServiceBusSender` from `CreateSender`, must be disposed to avoid handle leaks. This is poorly explained in the documentation, which focuses on the performance implication of repeat connection and link creation. The sample here disposes the client and sender, as necessary, but still causes excessive network traffic due to constantly reconnecting. [Cannot allocate more handles. The maximum number of handles is 4999. \(QuotaExceeded\)](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.AzureServiceBus/issues/75#issuecomment-950944161).

Comment: @mkjeldsen the ServiceBusClient actually doesn't implement the IDisposable so using it as a static to avoid re-instantiating is needed imo

Comment: @DaveFriedel, `ServiceBusClient` and `ServiceBusSender` implement `IAsyncDisposable` (but not `IDisposable`, indeed). This sample had a compilation error because of that, which I have now corrected. In any case, the key is to manage the lifetimes of the handles to avoid leaks -- a globally single `static` instance is one way to do so, yes, but that mechanism forcefully removes a lot of control from users and is not mechanically superior to alternatives that rely on explicit lifetime management.

Comment: To clarify: the second sample _in the question_ is incorrect. The sample in _this answer is correct but inefficient_; an efficient implementation would include some mechanism for reusing clients without failing to eventually dispose them. The answer by Sean Feldman is for a different question.

Answer (score 0):

you're in the right direction. There's no easy migration tool/sample as they are different libraries dealing with the same service (Azure Service Bus).

Comment: Is there more to it or am I good?